# Triggering a submit event not updating call count in Jest + Vue Test Utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

In Vue `2.6.12` with Jest: `"^27.5.1"` and `"@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",` I am trying to mock out an `async` method using jest. When I assert that my method has been called 1 time, it returns that it has not been called. Am I doing something blatantly wrong?

Update Email Test

```js
    import {mount} from '@vue/test-utils';
    import UpdateEmail from './components/update-email.vue';

    //validate form method testing
    test('should submit form', async () => {
        let wrapper = mount(UpdateEmail);
        const mockedFormSubmit = jest.spyOn(UpdateEmail.methods, 'updateEmail');
        // //Get our form fields
        await wrapper.find('#email').setValue('johndoe@test.com')
        await wrapper.find('#password').setValue('MyPassword');
        await wrapper.find('form').trigger('submit.prevent');

        expect(mockedFormSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

UpdateEmail Method

```js
    async updateEmail() {
      this.validateFields();

        try {
           await axios.post(this.updateEmailPath, {
            password: this.password,
            email: this.email
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        }
    },
```

Output in console when test runs:

```js
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      35 |         await wrapper.find('form').trigger('submit.prevent');
      36 |
    > 37 |         expect(mockedFormSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                                  ^
      38 |     });
      39 | });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Vue 2, the method must be mocked **before** mounting the component because the component's `.methods` are wired up only upon mounting:

```js
test('should submit form', async () => {

  const mockedFormSubmit = jest.spyOn(UpdateEmail.methods, 'updateEmail'); ✅
  let wrapper = mount(UpdateEmail);
  // const mockedFormSubmit = jest.spyOn(UpdateEmail.methods, 'updateEmail'); ❌

  ⋮
});
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-mock-form-submit?file=tests/unit/UpdateEmail.spec.js)

In Vue 3, methods can be mocked post-mount directly off of the `wrapper.vm` (starting with Vue 3.2.31).